# Patch command not found

Tags: centos5, patch-management

I tried to apply patch to my file with following command

> patch -p0 < foo.patch

I got the following output

> bash: patch: command not found

I have **Centos 5.x** server.

Please guide what to do in this case

Comment: You install it.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

All you need to do is

```
sudo yum install patch
```

Answer (score 4):

```
sudo yum install patch
```

If you have your yum repo configured correctly.

otherwise, find an rpm on the internet for your OS and do

```
rpm -ihv $urloftherpm
```